# HorizantalScrollView inside Viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have got `Viewpager` and I have got `horizantalscrollview` inside `viewpager.Horizantalscrollview` contains 2 layout. My purpose is `horizantalscrollview` is disable just when I click button it is scroll right to left. I did it but My problem is `viewpager` isnt working correctly.

I have tried this:

```
public class CustomHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

private boolean canScroll = false;
private scrollListener  listener=null;
public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}




@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (this.canScroll) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} 
public void enableScroll() {
    this.canScroll = true;

}

public void disableScroll() {
    this.canScroll = false;

}
public void setListener(scrollListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

}
```

I hope that I have explained my problem well. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why your `ViewPager` doesn't work is because the `HorizontalListView` consumes all `TouchEvents`.

A nice way to handle this is the method [`requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29).

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (this.canScroll) {
        // Disallow ViewPager to intercept touch events.
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } else {
        // Allow ViewPager to intercept touch events.
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2014-02-04**

Your button also consumes the `TouchEvents`. I find an [interesting discussion on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/wIqNP4fzJQc). Please read it, there are two possible solutions:

- first try the simple one and set the attribute `android:scrollHorizontally="false"`of your Button (you also can do this programatically: `setHorizontallyScrolling(false)`)
- second: you have to override the [`onTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) and [`onInterceptTouchEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) of your `ViewPager`.

Comment: i will try it and response result thanks for your answer

Comment: Unfortunately it wasnt working.Everthing similar.I have got button inside horizalscrollview,and scrollview inside viewpager.When start draging over the button my viewpager wasnt working but when start draging blan field it is working.

Comment: Unfortunately My wanted thing is horizontal scrollview disable just when want clicked button it is scrool right just when ı clicked It behave like panel.When user try to scrool , I want to scrool view pager I hope I can explain my problem thanks for your effort

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand whats your problem and your last comment addles me. I would give you the advise to post a new question where you explain your problem in a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).